# Блок Поделиться от Яндекса не отображается в Firefox

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

На странице размещён блок кнопок Поделиться. Отображается во всех браузерах кроме Firefox в версиях от 44 до 52. В консоли браузера выводится ошибка:

> TypeError: r.searchParams.forEach is not a function

Ошибка проявляется и при просмотре страницы блока "Поделиться":
https://tech.yandex.ru/share/

Comment: На русском stackoverflow принято задавать вопросы только на русском языке, пожалуйста переведите.

Comment: Проблемную страницу покажите.

Comment: @br3t ошибка появляется даже при просмотре страницы блока "Поделиться"

Answer (score 0):

Эту проблему исправили после 24 июня 2018, подробнее https://yandex.ru/blog/share/blok-podelitsya-ot-yandeksa-ne-otobrazhaetsya-v-firefox#5ae582cb5c10f900232481fa
Починено в этом пулле https://github.yandex-team.ru/share/share2/pull/195/files#diff-c30406b5f128a1cbb9b6d3dfcf16de6cL38